Framer motion - scroll to element once scrollYProgress reaches certain threshold
I am checking the scrollYProgress of my section element with useScroll(). Once scrollYProgress reaches a certain threshold, I want to scroll to my footer element with scrollIntoView().
Here is my code for my section element:
"use client";

export default function MySection() {
  const sectionRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: sectionRef
  });

  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, "change", (latestScrollYProgress) => {
    if (latestScrollYProgress >= 0.9) {
      const footerElement = document.getElementById("footer");
      if (footerElement) {
        console.log("has footer element");
        footerElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start"
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <section
      ref={sectionRef}
    >
      {/* Child elements here */}
    </section>
  )
}

Here is my footer element:
"use client";

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer id="footer">
      {/* Child elements here */}
    </footer>
  )
}

The code above does not seem to be working, even when a message from console.log() is shown. What seems to be the reason?
For additional context, NextJS with Tailwind is used here. scrollIntoView() also works when scrollYProgress is not being listened to.
